# strip all tags from string except anchor have class videoLink c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

i am trying to strip all tags from string paragraph except anchor tag which have class Videolink with regex.replace function can anybody help me out...!! thanks in advance... ***text is in urdu***

before i am using this function but it is deleting all tags

```
public string ScrubHtml(string value)
        {
            var step1 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(value, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", "").Trim();
            var Message_ = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(step1, @"\s{2,}", " ");
            return Message_;
        }
```

Comment: An HTML parser is probably the best approach; [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

Comment: give example of link

Comment: HTML is not a [regular language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la) and as such attempting to use regular expressions on it is a bad idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/643085

Answer (score 0):

Use a real html parser like [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), instead of Regex

Here is an example to get all links from a site

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var html = await client.GetStringAsync("http://google.com");

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var links = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                .Where(x => x.Name == "a")
                .Select(x=>x.Attributes["href"].Value)
                .ToList();
```